# How to handle exceptions globally in ReactiveUI 9.3.5?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, reactiveui

I recently upgraded to ReactiveUI  9.3.5, the documentation suggests to handle errors globally via `RxApp.DefaultExceptionHandler`:

```
// set at startup
RxApp.DefaultExceptionHandler = new GlobalErrorHandler();

public class GlobalErrorHandler : IObserver<Exception>
{
    public void OnNext(Exception error)
    {
        Debug.Write("An error occurred");
    }

    public void OnError(Exception error) { }

    public void OnCompleted() { }
}
```

When a command throws an exception, then the global error handler is called as expected.

The problem is that the app will afterwards still crash with an unhandled exception:

```
  // this crashes the app
  var command = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask(async () =>
        {
            throw new Exception();
        })
        .Execute()
        .Subscribe(x =>
        {                
            Debugger.Break();
        });
```

Is this the expected behaviour and what is the way to catch and handle exceptions in reactive code globally?

Previously I used `UserError` to throw and handle errors globally, but that's been depreceated.

Comment: Bit of a old version there. Why not go to 9.3.5 where that functionally is known to work.

Comment: @GlennWatson my mistake, I'm actually using  9.3.5 - I've updated my question

Comment: Same problem here, have you found a solution?

Comment: @MattF: sort of - I put a `.Catch()` on all the command executions, not nice...